# Trigger for hiding/showing radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have two radio buttons which act as an image selector. I want to listen for whether the first radio button is checked. If it is checked, I want the other radio button to be hidden.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
$('input[value="Dwarf.png|25|25"]').on("change", function(){

{
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Yes') {

        $('input[value="Gnome.png|25|25"]').hide();
        $('body').find('img[src$="./images/imgsel/Gnome.png"]').hide();

}

};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="pf_faction" id="pf_faction_0" value="Dwarf.png|25|25">
<img src="./images/imgsel/Dwarf.png" width="25" height="25" title="Dwarf" alt="Dwarf">

<input type="radio" name="pf_faction" id="pf_faction_1" value="Gnome.png|25|25">
<img src="./images/imgsel/Gnome.png" width="25" height="25" title="Gnome" alt="Gnome">
```

But this doesn't do anything. I've checked that the .hide() stuff is working by trying it with a doc ready function, and I know that bit works, but can't work out the rest of the puzzle.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I placed the code in to an executable where you can see you have at least one syntax error, caused by the inner `function() {`. This needs to be removed as it is not needed, and, if it worked, would prevent the code within it from being executed.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, I have removed that. Still not working however. Please see my updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `function(){` with some jQuery event that will be triggered when an input radio is checked.

Something like:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){ //do your logic });
```

When you select `$(this)` in that if statement, that won't know who `this` is. You need to provide the right context.

Comment: I did provide context for it though - 'this' refers to the dwarf input.

Answer (score 0):

That is do you want

```
$(function() {
 $('input[value="Dwarf.png|25|25"]').on('change', function(e){
    if ($(this).is( ":checked" )) {           
      $('input[value="Gnome.png|25|25"]').hide();
      $('img[src="./images/imgsel/Gnome.png"]').hide();
    }                   
 });
});
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/cateyusawa

Comment: Hey ryan, thanks but this doesn't solve my issue. I want to hide specific radio button by ID, not the nearest one.

Comment: You said: If it is checked, I want the other radio button to be hidden. So do u want hidden "$('input[value="Gnome.png|25|25"]')" ?

Comment: Yes ^ I want that input specifically to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
// script.js
$(function() {
    $('input[value="Dwarf.png|25|25"]').click(function(){

        $('input[value="Gnome.png|25|25"]').hide();
        $('body').find('img[src$="./images/imgsel/Gnome.png"]').hide();
    })
    $('input[value="Gnome.png|25|25"]').click(function(){
        $('input[value="Dwarf.png|25|25"]').hide();
        $('body').find('img[src$="./images/imgsel/Dwarf.png"]').hide();
    })
});
```

```
<!-- HTML  -->
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Hello World</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


<input type="radio" name="pf_faction" id="pf_faction_0" value="Dwarf.png|25|25">
<img src="./images/imgsel/Dwarf.png" width="25" height="25" title="Dwarf" alt="Dwarf">

<input type="radio" name="pf_faction" id="pf_faction_1" value="Gnome.png|25|25">
<img src="./images/imgsel/Gnome.png" width="25" height="25" title="Gnome" alt="Gnome">

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```